# ASP MVC Core 3x Async database call - What am I not getting?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, async-await

I am hoping someone can bring the light here because I am bouncing between one exception and another in VS and I am getting really fed up. I have read articles on how to perform async calls and seen code examples, yet for some reason I am somehow just not getting it according to VS.

I have a simple POCO, GetCompaniesResponse which will contain a collection of companies or errors depending on what happens:

```
public class GetCompanyResponse
{
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public List<ErrorResult> Errors { get; set; }

    public GetCompanyResponse()
    {
        Companies = new List<Company>();
        Errors = new List<ErrorResult>();
    }
}
```

All I am trying to do is convert a synchronous call that loads the companies from a database into an async call in order to free up the UI, whilst the data loads.

Here is the method I have converted:

```
    public async Task<GetCompanyResponse> GetCompaniesByQuery()
    {
        var response = new GetCompanyResponse();

        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration["Settings:DBConn"]))
            {
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (1000) company_id, company_name, postcode FROM dbo.tbl_companies";
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    response.Companies.Add(new Company
                    {
                        CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["company_id"]),
                        CompanyName = reader["company_name"].ToString(),
                        PostCode = reader["postcode"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.Errors.Add(new ErrorResult
            {
                ErrorMessage = e.Message
            });
        }
        
        return response;
    }
```

And my controller action is:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ByQuery()
    {
        var service = new TestService(_configuration);
        var response = await service.GetCompaniesByQuery();

        return View(response);
    }
```

The above method in VS simply keeps telling me I cannot return response because it cannot be converted. What am I doing wrong?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'TestApp.Models.GetCompanyResponse' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TestApp.Models.GetCompanyResponse>'  TestApp C:\Working Copies\TestApp\TestApp\Services\TestService.cs   59  Active
```

If I then try to extract the element of the task that strictly deals with the Companies property of the response POCO like so:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ByQuery()
    {
        var service = new TestService(_configuration);
        var response = new GetCompanyResponse();
        response.Companies = (await service.GetCompaniesByQuery()).ToList();

        return View(response);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompaniesByQuery()
    {
        var response = new List<Company>();

        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration["Settings:DBConn"]))
            {
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (1000) company_id, company_name, postcode FROM dbo.tbl_companies";
                conn.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    response.Add(new Company
                    {
                        CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["company_id"]),
                        CompanyName = reader["company_name"].ToString(),
                        PostCode = reader["postcode"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //not implemented yet
        }

        await Task.WhenAll((IEnumerable<Task>)response);
        
        return response;
    }
```

Whilst VS stops complaining about it, I then start running into invalid cast errors when the code is ran.

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestApp.Models.Company]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]'.
TestApp.Services.TestService.GetCompaniesByQuery() in TestService.cs
+
            await Task.WhenAll((IEnumerable<Task>)response);
TestApp.Controllers.HomeController.ByQuery() in HomeController.cs
+
            response.Companies = (await service.GetCompaniesByQuery()).ToList();
```

It makes no sense to me why this is the cause when the examples I have seen do exactly the same thing as above. What am I failing to comprehend here?

Comment: Why are you writing an async method **and not calling any async code in it**? At least use `ExecuteReaderAsync`.

Comment: "The above method in VS simply keeps telling me I cannot return response because it cannot be converted." Please edit your question to contain the **actual compiler error** that line gives you, as the code you've posted appears fine.

Comment: "in order to free up the UI" - that's not how web applications work. The UI isn't going to do anything in response to what's going on with the server until the HTTP response has been sent.

Comment: @Ian Can you be more specific? I was under the impression that the method itself is the unit of work I am trying to run asynchronously, not that I needed to make further asynchronous calls within it.

Comment: @mason you may well be right and my knowledge a little lacking here but if the action method is async, surely the response model on the view would load, and then any data it is loading from the database would load asynchronously via Ajax, otherwise I really don't see the point in having an async action method on a controller.

Comment: @DavidHirst Incorrect. "Async" here does not refer to AJAX in any way, shape or form.

Comment: The point in having an async controller action is to free up threads on the server to process other work. You'll gain scalability (assuming you're doing proper async calls, such as ExecuteReaderAsync) but at a tradeoff of slightly slower processing of individual requests. The `async` feature in C# and AJAX have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @DavidHirst In an ASP.Net context, the purpose of an `async` action method is to release the current ThreadPool thread to serve other HTTP requests whilst the I/O is being awaited. No response is sent to the client until the method completes.

Comment: OK it looks like I am way off the mark here then. Thanks all.

Comment: Your new async method doesn't contain any async code. So I would start by updating that method first.